# Pulling ROS2 packages in via bazel WORKSPACE mech in drake-ros_*

Tags: drake, ros2

Question related to Drake-ros's [#142](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros/issues/142) - I am unable to pull in the rviz_2d_overlay_plugins in drake_ros_viz via the bazel WORKSPACE mech. I have tried both focal and jammy rolling/humble distributions. I see the following error -

```
ERROR: no such package '@ros2//': Failed to setup @ros2 repository: './run.bash /home/arrowhead/.cache/bazel/_bazel_arrowhead/90cc0dfb7c9efd65bbcc1ee9dd934f8e/external/bazel_ros2_rules/ros2/scrape_distribution.py -i geometry_msgs -i rclcpp -i rclpy -i tf2_ros -i tf2_ros_py -i visualization_msgs -i rviz_2d_overlay_plugins -o distro_metadata.json' exited with 1
--- captured stderr ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arrowhead/.cache/bazel/_bazel_arrowhead/90cc0dfb7c9efd65bbcc1ee9dd934f8e/external/bazel_ros2_rules/ros2/scrape_distribution.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/arrowhead/.cache/bazel/_bazel_arrowhead/90cc0dfb7c9efd65bbcc1ee9dd934f8e/external/bazel_ros2_rules/ros2/scrape_distribution.py", line 46, in main
    distro = scrape_distribution(
  File "/home/arrowhead/.cache/bazel/_bazel_arrowhead/90cc0dfb7c9efd65bbcc1ee9dd934f8e/external/ros2/resources/ros2bzl/scraping/__init__.py", line 90, in scrape_distribution
    packages, dependency_graph = build_dependency_graph(
  File "/home/arrowhead/.cache/bazel/_bazel_arrowhead/90cc0dfb7c9efd65bbcc1ee9dd934f8e/external/ros2/resources/ros2bzl/scraping/__init__.py", line 50, in build_dependency_graph
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Cannont find package 'rviz_2d_overlay_plugins'
```

I see the package on ROS Index [here](https://index.ros.org/p/rviz_2d_overlay_plugins/github-teamspatzenhirn-rviz_2d_overlay_plugins/) and my relevant `WORKSPACE` Bazel bit is given below.

```py
ros2_archive(
    name = "ros2",
    include_packages = [
        "geometry_msgs",
        "rclcpp",
        "rclpy",
        "tf2_ros",
        "tf2_ros_py",
        "visualization_msgs",
        "rviz_2d_overlay_plugins"
    ],

    sha256_url = "https://build.ros2.org/view/Hci/job/Hci__nightly-cyclonedds_ubuntu_jammy_amd64/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/ros2-humble-linux-jammy-amd64-ci-CHECKSUM",  # noqa
    strip_prefix = "ros2-linux",
    url = "https://build.ros2.org/view/Hci/job/Hci__nightly-cyclonedds_ubuntu_jammy_amd64/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/ros2-humble-linux-jammy-amd64-ci.tar.bz2",  # noqa
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primary Suggestion**: You may want to consider installing ROS Humble directly onto your Jammy OS, and then use `ros2_local_repository` rather than `ros2_archive`: 
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros/blob/06dc6aa7d0237f4edb74130bcce8e9e78689d50c/bazel_ros2_rules/ros2/defs.bzl#L221-L239

Then you should be able to use a locally installed ROS 2 version, and install the package you want, either to `/opt/ros` or in a workspace that you're chaining.

FTR, in Anzu at TRI, we use `ros2_archive` presently for the following reasons (some of which are my opinions):

- We wanted to use ROS 2 Humble on Focal, possibly mixing multiple different versions along different checkouts.
- I want things to update only when I (we) precisely want. (For high confidence reproducibility, also to denoise `apt upgrade`)

  - For reproduciblity, I want us to maintain the ability to have *decent* reproducibility *without* aggressive containerization.

This means you should consolidate your development solely onto Jammy.
If you are already containerizing, then that should  hopefully not be too large of a jump.

**Alternative**: If you really want to maintain archives, is to build your own *extension* archive including the packages you want. Here's an example kinda-hack that I had shimmed into Anzu: 
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/4079be209bfbc282d4580b5b2979faa148e1f394/ros/drake_ros_example_layered_archive

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have some issues with `ros_local_archive` scraping local ROS2 installation on Jammy but I will make another post for that.

Comment: The other issues were addressed in this StackOverflow question! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75151171/unable-to-use-underlay-ros2-installation-with-drake-ros-as-an-external-in-a-baze/75214423#75214423