# Unable to use underlay ros2 installation with drake-ros as an external in a Bazel Workspace

Tags: ros, drake

Using `ros2_local_repository` following the ros-humble installation ([the debian way](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html)) yields errors the following CMAKE errors -

```
--- captured stderr ---
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/humble/share/quality_of_service_demo_cpp/cmake/ament_cmake_export_include_directories-extras.cmake:11 (message):
  Package 'quality_of_service_demo_cpp' exports the include directory
  '/opt/ros/humble/share/quality_of_service_demo_cpp/cmake/../../../include/quality_of_service_demo_cpp'
  which doesn't exist
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/quality_of_service_demo_cpp/cmake/quality_of_service_demo_cppConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_generator_c" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_generator_cpp" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_c" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs__rosidl_generator_py" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_image_tools" links to target
  "sensor_msgs::sensor_msgs_library" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a
  find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
  is missing?


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target "tf2::tf2" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_generator_c" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_c" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_generator_cpp" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_cpp" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target
  "geometry_msgs::geometry_msgs__rosidl_generator_py" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target "tf2_ros::tf2_ros" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Trying to build my `[outdoor_slam_ros2][1]` package with drake-ros' bazel rules.

Relevant snippet from `WORKSPACE`. Is there some other way to pull in packages and use via an overlay workspace?

```
# Use ROS 2
ros2_local_repository(
    name = "ros2",
    workspaces = ["/opt/ros/humble/"],
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the same error after installing `ros-humble-desktop`. The solution is to include just the packages you need from a workspace with the `include_packages` option to `ros2_local_repository()`.

```
ros2_local_repository(
    name = "ros2",
    include_packages = [
      "rclcpp",
    ],
    workspaces = ["/opt/ros/humble/"],
)
```

In the background `ros2_local_repository()` uses the CMake File API to "scrape" information about ROS 2 packages to build a `BUILD.bazel` file for the `@ros2` repo. That "scraping" works by generating a CMake package for each package in the ROS 2 workspace. The generated package tries to depend on everything in the ROS 2 package it's responsible for scraping. This can uncover bugs in the CMake logic of the ROS 2 package that might not be seen in typical use.

Take for example this one:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
  Target "empty_using_tf2_bullet" links to target "tf2_ros::tf2_ros" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

The bug is that `tf2_bullet` [publicly depends on `tf2_ros::tf2_ros`](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/04d420396afdaeaa5de28f58296d1e00b24d5ecb/tf2_bullet/CMakeLists.txt#L29), but does not tell downstream packages to `find_package(tf2_ros)` to get access to that target. The `tf2_bullet` package's `CMakeLists.txt` is missing the line `ament_export_dependencies(tf2_ros)` which would make downstream packages automatically `find_package(tf2_ros)` when they `find_package(tf2_bullet)`. The fact that this bug exists probably means that not many developers are using `tf2_bullet`, or they're also already directly or indirectly calling `find_package(tf2_ros)`.

Using the `include_packages` option avoids these kinds of bugs by instructing `ros2_local_repository()` to only scrape the ROS 2 packages that are actually needed, instead of scraping all of them in the workspace.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is awesome and helps in the understanding a lot :)